# Get blendshapes by name rather than by index

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3d, is it possible to access blendshapes by name instead of by their index?

```
float currentShape= myObj.GetBlendShapeWeight(2); //index 2
float currentShape= myObj.GetBlendShapeWeight.GetByName("Gwen_Stefani");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
public string [] getBlendShapeNames (GameObject obj)
{
    SkinnedMeshRenderer head = obj.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    Mesh m = head.sharedMesh;
    string[] arr;
    arr = new string [m.blendShapeCount];
    for (int i= 0; i < m.blendShapeCount; i++)
    {
      string s = m.GetBlendShapeName(i);
      print("Blend Shape: " + i + " " + s);
      arr[i] = s;
    }
    return arr;
}
```